# pass variable to bitbucket nodejs script

Tags: node.js, bitbucket-pipelines

I am using bitbucket, and I setup a token as secured variable in my pipeline settings.

I would like to use that token in my script, so I did :

```
  - step:
      name: 'Cancel Previous'
      script:
        - node ./pipelines/skip-previous.js $APP_PASSWORD
```

Now, I can't find a way to get that variable APP_PASSWORD...

in the node js, I do

```
const APP_PASSWORD = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log(process.argv);
```

but what is Get is

> [
> '/usr/local/bin/node',
> '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/pipelines/skip-previous.js',
> '$APP_PASSWORD'
> ]

i tried with `"` or `'` or `--` but nothing...

Comment: Did you tried `${APP_PASSWORD}`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `process.env.APP_PASSWORD` in your js code.

The APP_PASSWORD variable is an environment variable and therefore should be accessible through `process.env`